# Is there a special term for this type of alternate picking?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, picking, metal

I'm looking to see if there's a special word for a type of alternate picking commonly heard in metal that involves playing a series of notes on a lower string while also playing notes on a higher string in between.

Something like this:

The technique I'm looking for starts at around 25 seconds. I've noticed a lot of heavier metal guitar players utilize this technique, and I have a hard time playing any of these songs. I'm trying to find a good way to search for this type of playing to find relevant practice exercises.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for _string-skipping_ exercises?

Comment: Am I correctly assuming that [Bullet for my Valentine - Suffocating under Words of Sorrow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNzdVsajedM) is another example of the picking style you mean?

Comment: @Ian Yes the main riff for this song is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like string skipping which.  There is no special technique other than practice string skipping exercises slowly with a metronome until you can play clean.  As for alternate versus other picking methods that is up to you.  Mal Bay Grade 2 has some string skipping exercises near the end that are pretty tough to get fast and are worth the effort to work on.  I am sure you can find similar exercises in a book on shred guitar techniques.  But don't search for "alternate picking" search on "string skipping".